# UINavigationController visibleViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController, and one tab is a UINavigationController.  I have a search bar that goes to a certain view within the UINavigationController.  The problem is that if the first view is not pushed by the UINavigationController, than it crashes because my search doesn't recognize the visibleViewController from this call:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.MainTab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
FirstViewController *fVC = [navController visibleViewController];
```

What I don't understand is, before this code, I do this:

```
    self.MainTab.selectedIndex = 1;
```

This code on its own selects the viewController in that tab, where then the view gets loaded to my knowledge.  So shouldn't this be enough for the [navController visibleViewController] to get the current viewController?  Thanks.

Comment: What does `[navController visibleViewController]` return? And what is the crash message?

Comment: @sergio I get the unrecognized selector sent to instance for the crash message?  How do I check what visibleViewController returns since if it crashes, my FirstViewController doesn't have the right information right?

Comment: it seems that `navController` is no `UINavigationController`, that is why calling `visibleViewController` fails... are you sure about the index you are using to get it from `self.MainTab.viewControllers`?

Comment: @sergio Yeah I checked the index.  If I leave out the search code that I have in that block, and just use the self.MainTab.selectedIndex = 1, then I get the UINavigationController, with the first view in viewDidLoad pushed onto the stack.  Also, as long as I select that tab first, then go back to the home tab, this block of code runs, and the search selects the correct item.

Comment: @sergio I just tried this: if ([navController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) , and it does return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you explain in your question and comments, I understand that your code tries to access an object of type `FirstViewController`, supposedly the first view to be pushed on to your `UINavigationController`, when it has not yet been created.

On the other hand, if you first programmatically select the tab, the view is created and everything works fine. Indeed, that view is created in a `viewDidLoad` method that is run when the tab is selected.

The solution I would suggest is avoiding accessing the `UINavigationController` `visibleViewController` directly from your search tab; instead, let your search code access the model (as in Model-View-Controller) for your app and store there the result; then, from the mentioned `viewDidLoad` method again access the model to read the search result and update/show the UI.

This is the *clean* solution, IMO. If you want a sort of workaround to your current design, then check the `fVC` value you get back from `visibleViewController` and if it is not what expected, then instantiate the view properly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try *topViewController* instead of *visibleViewController*.

```
FirstViewController *fVC = [navController topViewController];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error.  Unrecongized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but I found another solution that might be helpful. In my case I was handling rotation differently for some viewControllers within my NavigationController, I did the following:

Subclass UINavigationController, then where needed in your new subclass you can access the current visibleViewController's title like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([[self visibleViewController].title isEqualToString:@"Special Case"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is not specific to rotation, this is just what I used it for.  The only thing you have to do is set your `self.title` for each of the viewControllers you are checking against in their `viewDidLoad`, if they are set in IB or are not set they will be `nil`.